# Firewire camera with OpenCv 2.4. not working

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, firewire

I am using OpenCV 2.4 with C++ for image processing and video streaming . I would like to know how we can use fire-wire camera like pixilink to capture frames? I tried the VideoCapture class but it seems to work with only usb cameras unlike firewire one. If some one has done same thing with firewire camera then kindly give some guidance how to do that?

Comment: @wolverinePk ...i also tried using Opencv2.4.2 with Prosilica firewire camera..but no success...i used SDK of the firewire camera...

Comment: i think your right , i could not find any other way as well..

Comment: I was able to make it work in my friend's system. Can you please tell me the outputs of the following commands :
testlibraw
lsmod

Answer (score 0):

You can capture images using firewire SDK or you can also [libdc1394 API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394/). I found libdc1394 to more reliable and easy to use and there are couple of examples available to get start.