# OpenCV with FireWire cameras on Windows (IEEE1394)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, firewire, libdc1394

I have read [Firewire 1394 camera with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597689/firewire-1394-camera-with-opencv), [Firewire camera with OpenCv 2.4. not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535969/firewire-camera-with-opencv-2-4-not-working), [ctypes error: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394) but I have found no working solution up to now.

**How to open a Firewire dc1394 camera on Windows with OpenCV?**

I installed it with `pip install opencv-python`. Is there a specific version of OpenCV to install to use the libdc1394 on Windows?

This code:

```
import cv2  
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE + 0)      # like in https://answers.opencv.org/question/203165/opencv-3-python-3-firewire-cameras/
# or is it this instead:
# cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE)
while True:
    ret_val, img = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
        break  # esc to quit
```

does not find any device. Is there something specific to be able to open FireWire cameras with OpenCV Python for Windows?

(see also this [opencv.org](https://answers.opencv.org/question/203165/opencv-3-python-3-firewire-cameras/) question)

Comment: Have you tried `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`? With OpenCV version 4.5.5 on Windows 10, I am getting: `DC1394:                      NO`. It is not so difficult to build OpenCV from sources with FireWire enabled. In case you never built OpenCV from sources, it is going to be a bit challenging at the first time.

Comment: Wonderful info @Rotem! Do you think there are premade OpenCV Python Releases with DC1394 included? For example Gohlke's page https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv I don't know if it includes this DC1394.

Comment: @Rotem If I achieve to build a custom OpenCV version with this, do you think `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE + 0)` is the right way to connect? (like in my question's last link). Or would it be `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE)`? or something else?

Comment: I think it should be `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE, 0)` but I never tried to capture FireWire. I don't know if there is premade releases with DC1394.

Comment: @Rotem I'm not sure, but it seems to be the opposite order for the parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63423961/1422096. Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes, my mistake: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_FIREWIRE)`